# Is there a fax machine on the ISS ?

Tags: iss, communication

I know some older space stations had fax machine (since Sayult 7 at least).
Do they still have it on the ISS ?

Does is support in/out or only one way communications ?

Comment: Shuttle had a fax machine of sorts (teleprinter). ISS just has a regular printer.

Comment: If you can send a PDF up to the space station and print it if needed, I can see little practical need or use for a dedicated fax machine. Remember, every gram you ship up there costs money!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISS does not have a fax machine.  There are two Epson 800 inkjet printers onboard connected to the ISS local area network.  Any document sent up from the ground that the crew needs to print, can be printed on this printer.

Next year, the aging Epson 800s are planned to be replaced with a new HP Envy, specially modified for free-fall.

[Source](http://mashable.com/2017/11/02/nasa-updates-international-space-station-printer/#uZf0lrmJbPqC)